# Compact Code to Walk JTokens (Newtonsoft) without a pyramid of null checks

Tags: c#, json

Scenario: changing a the name associated with an ID in a database table requires updating of zero or more serialized JSON values in another database table that contain both the name and ID (the JSON objects have different "schemas" but use the same property chain if requiring an update and the IDs are synthetic keys that can collide with other keys stored in the object).

Is there a clean alternative to a pyramid of `JToken foo = json["bar"] as JToken; if ( foo != null){...` ?

The matching property is several layers deep.

Assigning, null checking, repeat: it works but the resulting method length is more than a screen and screams that there has to be a smarter way. `foo["bar"]["propA"]...` would be ideal but results in null references in some cases.

Is there a more compact way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null conditional operator can reduce your code greatly:

```
var tkn = foo["whatever"]?["andnext"]?["andnext"]...etc.
```